# ImportError: cannot import name 'winrandom'

Tags: python, pycrypto

I know that this question has already a ton of answers but unfortunately this hasn't fixed the issue for me. I want to run some code using PyCrytpo but winrandom doesn't want to get import.

All the other posts are for earlier releases of python. I am using Python 3.6.5 and renaming code within nt.py file to "`from . import winrandom`" doesn't do the trick for me.

Do you have any suggestions or is a rollback the only opportunity?

Windows 10
Python 3.6.5
Anaconda

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-b6fe4d249eef>", line 1, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

  File "C:\Users\Markus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 78, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random

  File "C:\Users\Markus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import OSRNG

  File "C:\Users\Markus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.OSRNG.nt import new

  File "C:\Users\Markus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import winrandom

ImportError: cannot import name 'winrandom'
```

Comment: I would vote that using a crypto library that is no longer maintained and 5 years dead is a high security risk. Consider looking for another library

Comment: @FlyingTeller thanks for your input. Which library would you choose instead of crypto?